# Reportlab wordwrap not adding hyphen

Tags: reportlab, word-break

I'm using Reportlabs paragraphstyles default wordwrap which, along with   as needed gives me what I want except for one case, when a long word won't fit in a small cell.  Currently it's wrapping properly but I want it to insert a hyphen when it wraps.  I'm getting:

```
Gainesvil
le
```

but want:

```
Gainesvil-
le
```

My styling is:
`ParagraphStyle('events', fontName = "Arial', fontSize=10, parent=styles['Normal'],  leading=1.1, alignment= TA_LEFT)`

The cell is city name and is narrow.  Word wrapping happens when the font is increased too much. This is my first Reportlab project and I can't find what I need in the documentation or anywhere else. I can't use  'splitLongWords = False' because then it overwrites the next column.

Thank you.

Tried wordWrap='CJK' then wordwrap='LTR', couldn't figure out wordwrap options, only found 'LTR' in an example.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across the answer while searching for something else.  Apparently Robin Becker solved this:

```
pip install pyphen

import pyphen
```

Added to paragraphStyle:

```
hyphenationLang = 'en',
```

That's it.  It works in paragraphs.

[Discussion and solution:](https://groups.google.com/g/reportlab-users/c/sfNyfItj0g8)